# Deeplab: "Failed to find all Cityscapes modules"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to run the tensorflow [DeepLab tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md) on the cityscapes dataset. I downloaded the gtFine dataset and cloned into the cityscapesScripts folder, and set up the directories as recommended in the tutorial. When I ran the following line from the tutorial,
`sh convert_cityscapes.sh`,
 I received an error message stating **"Failed to find all Cityscapes modules"**.

I checked the [cityscapesScripts documentation](https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts/blob/master/cityscapesscripts/helpers/csHelpers.py) and I think I am missing the labels module, which is likely causing the error. Where can I clone or download the missing module(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dependencies for `sh convert_cityscapes.sh`, there's a file with invalid syntax.

You can get it to work on Python3 by commenting out the line

> print type(obj).**name**

from cityscapeScripts/helpers/annotation.py line 238

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me. I edited the question to refer to the correct script. Do you know why the print __name__ function causes problems with python 3 and not python 2?

Comment: @Kritika type(obj) appears to return a string, for which I could not find a "name"- method. Same thing with Python2, so I do not know why switching to Python2 would have worked.