# Deeplab: error when converting dataset to TFRecord by running "sh convert_cityscapes.sh"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, deeplab

I am trying to run [DeepLab: Deep Labelling for Semantic Image Segmentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) on my laptop for a while now. I have followed the [installation](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/installation.md) guide and have run *python deeplab/model_test.py* successfully.

The next step is running [Cityscape](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md) dataset, where I am stuck now.

Following things have been done so far:

I am using *Windows 10* and I have configured the path with this "/root/datasets/cityscapes/". Installed the cityscapes API and followed the recommended directory structure. You will find the cityscapeScritps files [here](https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts).

When I run the `convert_cityscapes.sh` command in *MINGW64* I get the following error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./cityscapes/cityscapesscripts/preparation/createTrainIdLabelImgs.py", line 27, in
from cityscapesscripts.helpers.csHelpers import printError
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cityscapesscripts'**

I have seen [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220632/deeplab-failed-to-find-all-cityscapes-modules) errors herein *stackoverflow* but nothing seems to solve mine.

I am using *python 3.6.7*, *tensorflow-gpu 1.13.1* and *cuda 10.0*.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already cloned the [cityscapesscript](https://github.com/mcordts/cityscapesScripts), try adding it's absolute path to $PYTHONPATH.